# Cant retrieve data from JSON Array Firebase

Tags: ios, json, swift

Language: Swift 3.0 --- IDE: Xcode 8 --- Project: Firebase TableView

I want to retrieve data from my Firebase database. This is my JSON database :

[image]

The error I get is lldb when it tries to get firstName which means there are no such values. I think the problem is that this code does not get in the 0,1,2 which are the "objects" with the values and I don't know how to get there.

Here is my code where I try to retrieve the data and load them on a TableViewController :

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

struct employee {
    let firstName: String!
    let lastName: String!
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    var rootRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
    var employees = [employee]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        rootRef.child("employees").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let firstName = snapshot.value!["firstName"] as! String
            let lastName = snapshot.value!["lastName"] as! String

            self.employees.insert(employee(firstName:firstName,lastName:lastName), at: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return employees.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for:
            indexPath) as! TablevieCell

        let employee = employees[indexPath.row]

        cell.firstNameLabel.text = employee.firstName


        return cell

    }

}
```

I want someone to tell me how to get in my objects inside an Array on JSON if thats the problem or help me with any way. Thanks

**EDIT**

print(snapshot.value) prints:

```
Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x610000055750>(
{
    firstName = John;
    lastnName = Doe;
},
{
    firstName = Anna;
    lastnName = Smith;
},
{
    firstName = Emma;
    lastnName = Jackson;
}
)
)
```

Comment: just try to `print(snapshot.value)` and tell me response

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 I added the print. Removing queryOrderedByKey() doesn't do anything. Same print.

Comment: because your key is 0,1,2... your data converted into array ..and if you delete number1 .. it gives you null ... so better use some string for key

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 So how do I access an array on JSON with key 0,1,2....?